# How to gradually decrease opacity of model?

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-8

I have been searching for this matter for a long time and slowly I begin to think that this option is not available in XNA for Windows Phone.

I am trying to get a 3D-Model to be drawn at 50% opactity/transparency.

The most promising piece I found is following:

```
//1. Set the alpha blend mode for the graphics device with:

graphics.GraphicsDevice.RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable = true;
graphics.GraphicsDevice.RenderState.SourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha; // source rgb * source alpha
graphics.GraphicsDevice.RenderState.AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.One; // don't modify source alpha
graphics.GraphicsDevice.RenderState.DestinationBlend = Blend.InverseSourceAlpha; // dest rgb * (255 - source alpha)
graphics.GraphicsDevice.RenderState.AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.InverseSourceAlpha; // dest alpha * (255 - source alpha)
graphics.GraphicsDevice.RenderState.BlendFunction = BlendFunction.Add; // add source and dest results

//2. Set the alpha value in the BasicEffect for the model:
effect.Alpha = 0.5f; // Creates a 50% translucent object.
```

But GraphicsDevice.RenderState.AlphaBlendEnable isn't even available in XNA for Windows Phone.

So is there any way to achieve that effect?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the age of this question, you likely have already found an answer, but I thought I would share my approach either way.

Assuming your model has a [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_and_concave_polygons) shape, you can try pre-rendering the model's texture to a render target with a SpriteBatch, using the appropriate alpha value. Then apply that render target to your model. That way, you won't have to bother with RenderStates.

```
RenderTarget2D modelTargetTex; // assuming these are defined elsewhere
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
// draw your model's texture to a render target, with a specific alpha value.
// put this at the start of your Draw() method
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(modelTargetTex);    
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent); // so the alpha blending will work correctly
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
spriteBatch.Draw(originalModelTexture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White * yourAlphaValue);
spriteBatch.End();
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null); // don't forget to unset the render target
```

Once that is done, you can simply assign the render target to your model (`basicEffect.Texture = modelTargetTex;`) through whatever method you use to draw them.
This method would work best on convex models because a concave shape might show graphical artifacts when polys overlap.